# How can get the last value of column

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

How can I retrieve the last entered value of the column in the database (MS ACCESS 2007)

I used the following code

```
String sql = "SELECT Last(RegNumber) FROM Death ";
```

but it does not work in MS ACCESS and when I run the program Error generates as

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column not found
```

but I have created a column in database as `RegNumber`

I am using Java for programming in which I used this query

EDIT:

RegNumber is in  String form not in integer form so I cant use DESC or ASC

Please help me

Comment: That query does work in MS Access natively, providing as you've stated that the correct columns are in the correct tables. It's possible that the Java SQL plugin does not recognize the command, and is interpreting this as a column named "Last(RegNumber)"

Comment: If you are creating records in a multi-user environment and you wish to return the ID of the record you have just created, this is not a good way to get it.

Comment: Agreed; the methods given so far imply that you wish to retrieve the last row of a certain query, not to get the last inserted/edited row. There are other functions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort your table by whatever criteria you'd like and use `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable ORDER BY RegNumber ASC`.

Or `ORDER BY incrementingId DESC`

Basically there must be some logical order to the sorting for what you refer to as the "last entered column" (which I assume means row, not column)

EDIT: Your function is correct in Access, and should return the correct value. However Java may not interpret it correctly. Try your query in an Access native query, then try debugging your Java. If it's simply that Java does not support this function, consider using the built in ResultSet() functions in Java.sql

```
ResultSet rs = ....;
rs.last();
int RegNumber = rs.getRow();
```

Comment: Top *n* will return more than *n* values where there are matches, so you must sort by both the desired column and a unique id if you require *n* results.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the `last()` function in `MS ACCESS`, but I have another idea:

Usually there is an automatically generated `id` for each `table`, so you can sort on it and get the first record from the result set like this:

```
SELECT RegNumber
FROM Death 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Last() and First() are indeed MS Access SQL functions. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/first-last-functions-HP001032232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That depend of your database structure.

Typically with table come some unique identifier, if you are sure that it comes **always** in order to database you could use function `MAX` to retrieve the identifier and then whole row.

Another scenario is just to a timestamp columns that describe the time when column was created , this approach satisfying if the sequence is really crucial if not the `id` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Following will return the last and lastest RegNumber :

```
SELECT RegNumber FROM Death ORDER BY RegNumber DESC
```